# How to use .where().equal() after a populate() in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

That's my two models :

```
var OfferSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type : String
    },
    commerce: {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Commerce'
    }
});
```

An offer contains a commerce :

```
var CommerceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

Then i just want to get all the offers that have a commerce named "Haircut" by example, so i request that :

```
module.exports.getOffresByName = function(req,callback){
    var name= req;
    Offre.find()
        .populate('commerce')
        .where('commerce.name').equals('Haircut')
        .exec(callback);
}
```

And i get nothing from that.. ( And i know that i have an offer with commerce named 'Haircut', so the problem is with my request )

Can you help me please ? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i succed, i toke an other way !

```
module.exports.getOffresByName = function(req,callback){
        var name= req;
        var result = [];
        Offre.find()
        .populate('commerce') 
        .exec(function(err, offer){
            if(err) return err;
            var cmp= 0;
            for(var i= 0; i<offer.length; i++){
                if( offer[i].commerce.name== name){
                    result[cmp]= offer[i];
                    cmp++;
                }
            }
            callback(err, result);
        });
```